# 'Bad token in signature' with numba & @guvectorize

Tags: python, numba

I am trying decorator `@guvectorize` with a function that outputs a [m,2] array. (m is depending the size of the input)

When using following function signature, I get an error.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize

@guvectorize('void(float64[:], float64, uint32[:,2])', '(m),()->(m,2)', nopython=True)
def array_copy(data, delta, result):
    for i, val in np.ndenumerate(data):
        # Open i.
        i, = i
        result[i,:] = [i, int(val)+delta]

data = np.arange(3, dtype='float64')
res = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 2), dtype='uint32')
array_copy(data, 3, res)
```

This function is only here to support the example.
Here is the error message.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-63f8983bbf61>", line 5, in <module>
    def array_copy(data, delta, result):

  File "/home/pierre/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/decorators.py", line 177, in wrap
    guvec = GUVectorize(func, signature, **kws)

  File "/home/pierre/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/decorators.py", line 49, in __new__
    return imp(func, signature, identity=identity, cache=cache,

  File "/home/pierre/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/ufuncbuilder.py", line 298, in __init__
    self.sin, self.sout = parse_signature(signature)

  File "/home/pierre/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/sigparse.py", line 49, in parse_signature
    outputs = list(parse(outs))

  File "/home/pierre/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/sigparse.py", line 35, in parse
    raise ValueError('bad token in signature "%s"' % tok[1])

ValueError: bad token in signature "2"
```

Please, what is wrong? How may I specify that `result` will have 2 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current implementation of Numba doesn't implement all the features defined in [Numpy's GUFunc signatures](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/generalized-ufuncs.html#details-of-signature), particularly fixed dimensions.

The trick is to pass the result array twice, so the dimensions of the result are inferred from that parameter.

The following example vectorizes a function that calculates the sum and product of each row vector of 3 elements:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize

@guvectorize('void(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:])',
             '(m),(n)->(n)',
             nopython=True)
def sum_and_product(data, dummy, result):
    result[0] = data[0] + data[1] + data[2]
    result[1] = data[0] * data[1] * data[2]
```

Then:

```
data = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], dtype=float)
data
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [7., 8., 9.]])
res = np.empty((3, 2), dtype=float)
res = sum_and_product(data, res)
res
array([[  6.,   6.],
       [ 15., 120.],
       [ 24., 504.]])
```

Notice that the signature specifies the dimensions of a single vector and, consequently, the code in the function operates on a single vector.